# Delta query for group properties not accurate for classification changes

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We enforce base controls to Office 365 groups that are dependent on the data classification value.  We have two ways these controls get applied:

1. Through a Graph subscription which automatically applies a set of base controls to an Office 365 group
2. A full scan to ensure each Office 365 group with a data classification value is assigned the correct base controls

We are trying to make the 1st option execute more efficiently by only proceeding with checking/applying the base controls if the data classification property changes.  The delta query for group appears to be bugged; if the classification property changed values, it does not correctly report this. Any property that has been changed has a "null" value.  Also the visibility property is always there.

Repro steps:

1: Initialization.  Get delta token.

```
 HTTP GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta&$deltatoken=latest
```

2: Make a classification change to an Office 365 group.  Make a description change to another Office 365 group.

3: Delta Query.

```
HTTP GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta?$deltatoken=DeltaToken
Prefer:return=minimal
```

Response is:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#groups",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta?$deltatoken=NextDeltaToken",
    "value": [
        {
            "classification": null,
            "description": null,
            "visibility": null,
            "id": "Group1ID"
        },
        {
            "description": null,
            "visibility": null,
            "id": "Group2ID"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: Forgot to add... Microsoft [docs mention](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_delta) a `null` value means the value is empty or the property has not changed.  This observation doesn't reflect the docs.

Comment: Does removing the `Prefer` change the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Removing the "Prefer" header returns a data set that is less specific - it returns all attributes regardless of whether they have been modified or not.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is are these values still `null` when you don't use the `prefer` header?